# Using .change() on .each()

Tags: jquery, listener

**Desired behavior**

I have a set of input fields of `type="number"`, and against each of these, I want to use JQuery's `.change()`.

**My attempt**

I figured I'd run through the inputs with `.each()` and from there, use `.change()` on them.

I tried using `$("input[type=number]").each().change(function() { ... })` but this produces the following error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

I have verified that the preceding `$("input[type=number]")` works, and is fetching the input fields I want to add the listeners to.

**Question**

Can I not use `.each()` and `.change()` like this? Am I even on the right track?

Comment: you can use like this `$("input[type=number]").each(function() {
 $(this).change(function() {
    })
})`

Comment: Firstly when using `each()` you should provide it an anonymous function which performs the logic required on each element in the matched set. Secondly, you don't need to use `each()` at all in this case; just call `change()` directly.

Comment: jQuery will internally already use a loop to bind the event handler to all elements in the selector. You could say that it takes the selector and puts each DOM element that corresponds to it in an object (the jQuery object), and then assigns an event handler to each element in that object.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `each` there. `each` is for loops. Use `change` directly.

```
$("input[type=number]").change(function() {
    // do somthing on event
});
```

If you want to use `each`, it's possible too. It's the same result as before, but more code and slower, because you don't really need the loop here.

```
$("input[type=number]").each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
        // do something here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `each()` with a callback function

**LIKE**

```
$("input[type=number]").each(function(){  
         $(this).change(function() { // Change Code goes here. });
});
```

**NOTE**

Simple `change` event will work in your case

```
$("input[type=number]").change(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
$("input[type=number]").change(function(e){
     // What u want to do
});
```

jQuery already uses a loop to apply the same event Handler to all elements of the selector. each is used when u have to loop through all elements of selector manually.

Read more about .each() here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Read more about .change() event handler here  https://api.jquery.com/change/